# Cannot get repository contents as .zip file (zipball) in Octokit.net

Tags: c#, .net, zip, github-api, octokit.net

I am using [Octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) `version 0.9.0` (GitHub API for .NET) for getting zip contents of few repositories.

I already have the list of repositories I need but I am having trouble with getting the the content of the repositories as .zip files (called zipball)

#### What I've tried so far

```
// ... client = new Client(...);
// some authentication logic...
// some other queries to GitHub that work correctly
var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/SomeUser/SomeRepo/zipball";
var response = await this.client.Connection.Get<byte[]>(
        new Uri(url),
        new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        null);
var data = response.Body;
var responseData = response.HttpResponse.Body;
```

#### Problems with my attempts

1. `data` is null
2. `responseData.GetType().Name` says the `responseData` is of type string
3. When I try `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.HttpResponse.Body.ToString());` I get invalid zip file

[image: Value of response.HttpResponse.Body]

#### Quesion

**What is the correct way to get zipballs of repositories after being authenticated using Octokit.net library?**

I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/784) in octokit.net repository.

Comment: The response data looks like a zip file as "PK" is the identifier for zip. Even if it the binary data is converted to string I would not encode it with ascii (did you try it with `Encoding.utf8.GetBytes()`?)

Comment: @habakuk, yes, I did, but still no luck. I've tried all predefined encodings and didn't have any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the source of Octokit I think this is not possible (as of version 0.10.0):

See [Octokit\Http\HttpClientAdapter.cs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/v0.10.0/Octokit/Http/HttpClientAdapter.cs#L79)

```
// We added support for downloading images. Let's constrain this appropriately.
if (contentType == null || !contentType.StartsWith("image/"))
{
    responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
else
{
    responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The response body (`responseData`) is converted to an unicode string and, thus, it's mangled and not binary the same. See my [PR792](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/pull/792) (need to replace the if statement with `if (contentType == null || (!contentType.StartsWith("image/") && !contentType.StartsWith("application/")))`) to fix this (then it's a byte array. Writing possible using `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.zip", (byte[])responseData);`).

Comment: Great work! Thanks. I will wait it to be merged and will reward you with best answer and the bounty. :)

Comment: I correctly answered this question (it's not working ATM) and additionally added a workaround, so I think accepting this question is the right thing...

Comment: I agree with you. I will wait 2 more days and will award you with the bounty, too.

Comment: it just got merged! ;)